# Show that if $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $p$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that if $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $p$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

I think I probably have to use something related to norm to solve this problem but I can't seem to figure out anything. Can someone suggest how I can solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222907/primes-in-gaussian-integers?rq=1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013734/prime-elements-in-the-gaussian-integers?rq=1).

Answer (score 3):

If $p=(a+bi)(c+di)$ then
$$p^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$$
Therefore $a^2+b^2$ is $1$, $p$ or $p^2$. If it is $1$ or $p^2$ it is easy to conclude that $p$ is a prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$. If it is $p$ we arrive at a contradiction taking mod $4$.

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand your proof. I thought i am supposed to prove if p |ab then p|a or p |b in Z[i]. I can't see where there is shown.

Comment: @123 It's been 8 years, but that's the definition of a prime, not an irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\mathbf Z[\mathrm i]$ is a euclidean domain. Hence $p$ not being prime means it is reducible, say $$p=(a+b\mathrm i)(c+d\mathrm i)$$
Compute the norm of both sides and conclude that $p$ is the sum of two squares. Is that possible?

Comment: This is exactly the answer given already [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013734/prime-elements-in-the-gaussian-integers?rq=1).

Comment: Didn't know. There are many more details in the answer you mention.

Comment: I mean the answer by Amitai Yuval. Anyway, the question really is a duplicate, isn't it ?

Comment: I don't know well which questions are duplicate, as I haven't been a member of this site for a very long time, but this one is.