# Prove Gaussian Integer is prime?

Tags: gaussian-integers

How can I prove that a Gaussian integer is prime?
For instance, how can I prove that $7+0i$ is a prime number?

On wikipedia, I found that a Gaussian integer is prime either if its norm is a prime in the real numbers, or if either the real or imaginary part of the number is zero, while the other part is of the form 4+3n, but this doesn't seem like a sufficient proof.

Comment: A start is to prove there's no Gaussian integer with norm 7.

Comment: Just a curiosity: is it a homework question from your number theory class?

Comment: Also [Prime elements in the gaussian integers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013734)

Comment: Not entirely a duplicate of the other threads, as both of them are about $4k+3$ primes only. Fry's question also is about the fact that for non-real $z$, $z$ is prime if and only if $z^*z$ is prime.